# Updating the content of an embded object with files using JS and JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, embed

I am basically trying to make a web application where I have one pdf file loaded at once. So my main problem is how to I remove the current PDF file being shown and load the next based on my variable name which is basically just an integer dedicating which file to load(my files are name with numbers 1-72). At the moment nothing happens when i press the Next or Back button. Here is the code any input much appreciated.

```
$document.ready(function() {
var pageNumber = 1;
var doc = "Induction/" + pageNumber + ".pdf";
var parent = $('embed#file').parent();

$('#Back').click(function(){
    if(pageNumber > 2){
    pageNumber -= 1;
    doc = null;
    doc = "<embed id ="file" src="'Induction/' + pageNumber + '.pdf'" />"
    var newDoc = $(doc);
    $('embed#file').remove();
    parent.append(newDoc);
    }
    else{
        alert("No previous documents found");
        pageNumber = 1;
    }
});
$('#Next').click(function(){
    pageNumber += 1;
    if(pageNumber > 72){
        alert("Congratulations you reached the end of the Induction Course");
        pageNumber = 1;
    }
    doc = null;
    doc = "<embed id="file" src="'Induction/' + pageNumber + '.pdf'" />"
    var newDoc = $(doc);
    $('embed#file').remove();
    parent.append(newDoc);
  });
 });
```

In a way its a custom made pagination without choosing the pages by numbers rather by Next and Back button. However at the moment it does not load the next pdf file not the previous. I spent 2 days on this and looking over the internet and on this site too but no question found to dynamically update the content of the embed src tag with a PDF file.

Answer (score -1):

change "`if (pageNumber > 72)`" to "`if (pageNumber < 72)`"